# Theme definition in Android

Tags: android

I have a theme define in my `style.xml` such as `name="Theme.ABC"`, in my `Androidmenifest.xml`, I can refer it as `android:theme="@style/Theme.ABC"`,                                         but how can I refer it in the code?

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate`:   `setTheme(android.R.style.YourTheme)`.

You can find out more on how to set themes for you app [here](http://www.anddev.org/applying_a_theme_to_your_application-t817.html).

Comment: Its not "yourTheme", it is "your.Theme" i.e. the name has a '.'

Comment: Well, I don't think is good practice to use `.` when defining names. Change the Theme name to `Theme_ABC` see if that solves the problem.